# Where can I get data for traffic signals, stop signs, and other sign assets/inventory?

Tags: data

I'm working on a project involving roads.  The quality of the service would benefit from knowing if a given road is continuous or if it's broken up by stop signs, traffic signals, and other things that effect a motorist.

I haven't found anything googling around online.  I also contacted my local city government, but they only grant access to the data for city projects.  I'm guessing most areas would have similar rules.

Is there another source, public or commercial, that could help me out?  Or am I out of luck?

EDIT - I should note that I'm looking for data in the USA.

Comment: For what country? Could the data from openstreetmap be complete enough for your locality?

Comment: USA.  In my particlar city I didn't find any information.  Would there be other areas in the country that have this info?

Comment: I would suggest revising your question to include these additional details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Traffic / transportation guy here.

Usually a quick phone call to your state DOT or city planning / transportation planning division will suffice. What you also need are "turning patterns", and lane configurations. Ask for AADT and AADTT counts as well as peak hour counts, and 30 or 15 minute interval counts.  in cities where there are weigh in motion classifiers ask for that data as well, as it is important to any transportation data analyst

I've gotten data through Shapefiles, others through excel. and once I collected data tat wasn't digitized. So don't expect jurisdictions to have the same data formats as you.

**EDIT**

As a heads up, most states would **refuse** to give you sign diagrams.

Second update, is that they can charge you for the data. They don't charge for the collection, but they do charge for digitizing it. It's weird like that

Comment: @Eric - If you have any other transpo related questions please don't hesitate to ask

Answer (score 2):

Try your state department of transportation. Failing that try a FOI request to your city (after all your taxes paid for the data).

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure Navteq now includes that information in one of their data packages. It may be through traffic.com or through one of their many data packages.

Other than that - get out there man and start putting it into OSM